# AttributeError in numpy (OCR)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ocr, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to implement Optical Character Recognition (OCR) using tensorflow and have imported the MNIST data from the tensorflow library. However, I encountered an error which is shown in this [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXea8.png).

Here is the **python** code that I used:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
```

Comment: Please post the error message as text not the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the TensorFlow and NumPy versions are compatible. Check the versions using:

```bash
pip show numpy tensorflow
```

I am using:

- numpy==1.23.5
- tensorflow==2.12.0

and am able to execute the below.

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```